# Can't debug with Chrome Dev Tools on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome-devtools

I ran (first instance of) Chrome this way: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222**

I installed **Chrome devTools for Eclipse**.
I created a new Debug Configuration as explained at https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/ and shown in the screenshoot.

I click "Apply" and then "Debug".

After few seconds error is **"'Launching Chrome' has ecnountered a problem. Failed to get tabs for debugging. connection timed out"**.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

[image]

Comment: At the said project URL, you should have noticed a red note saying, "The project is no longer actively maintained". The "Wip backend" "Google Chrome" version in your screenshot should back this up.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? I mean: how shall I debug Javascript and see html/css errors (such as: image not found) in Eclipse?

Comment: In brief: the latest version of Chrome DevTools for Java will not work with any of the recent Chrome versions. Please use built-in Chrome DevTools instead.

Comment: what do you mean by "built-in Chrome DevTools"? (I Googled it without satisfying result)

Comment: I mean https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

Comment: now I got it. I know it. But I need to debug it in Eclipse. because it's a Phonegap app which shows perfectly on Chrome, but with bugs on phone (and within Eclipse)